# Best method for checking if IonCube Loader is installed

Tags: php, ioncube

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
if(extension_loaded("IonCube Loader")) {     
  // Yes
}
else {
  // No
}
?>
```

I'm just concerned that this won't work across every server with IonCube enabled. It seems pretty standard, but I've never needed to check before. Is this the best way to check, or is there a better method I should be using?

Comment: I am sorry, but is there a point to this? If you try to run an IonCube script on a server where it isn't loaded, that won't work and you'll get an error message.

Comment: Yeah, there's a point. I'm running a script to download an encoded script from a server and run it. If IonCube isn't enabled, the whole app will fail. Checking for IonCube saves me a server request and prevents the error message you are referring to.

Comment: For me it's also easier to check for it than digg on the logs because a blank screen...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the extension is not installed this will return you false, so as far as I know it is the correct way to check if an extension is available to use.

Another option is to use [get_loaded_extensions()](http://php.net/get_loaded_extensions). This returns you an array with available extension names. You could check if this arrays contains your desired extension.

Comment: $gefunden = false;
foreach (  get_loaded_extensions() as $number => $extension_name )
{

    if ( (strpos( strtolower($extension_name) , "ioncube" )) === false) {
       // do nothing
    } 
    else
    {
        $gefunden = true;
    }

}

Answer (score 5):

Actually i use SSH for the most of the things, including file copy.
When i need to check for ionCube loader the easier way for me it's just `php -m`.

Zend modules are listed on the bottom, due to the alphabetical order.

My output (last 2 lines):
`[Zend Modules]
the ionCube PHP Loader`.

For other options i used php -m | grep -v grep | grep MODULENAME.
If it's loaded is listed, otherwise you will get empty. (except if you forgot the grep -v grep pipe).

Comment: As the ionCube Loader is foremost a PHP engine extension, you can also use php -v and grep there.

Answer (score 5):

Here the PHP code encrypted with latest encoder v9.0(PHP 5.6/7.0), if ionCube loader is working you should see text "working", if you see blank page check for php logs:

```
<?php //0046b
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);

?>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=
```

Here PHP code encoded with legacy encoder 8.3(PHP 5.6 and below):

```
<?php //0046b
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);

?>
HR+cPp7q/tHOKq74dpvDQdk0enKwrkMD5yeF5eIiq+jd6h+ygyi99Yw9v+skX6plOCkD0S6vxDVT
g0nNVh2ujlRTSIiRAeEKpFhEG5BUvsr+EDaYN5HxECz/I9hYPAwp8hOqYfRctH5qT/1rYIX59wku
VRQDHVPzAMbv4kcSC/d/76RrKED24mpGOTteHWb4gyV5wkMY3lauJ2Kt525x+66BeXwGFubP+Ty4
bTvQZAlcRrNw7vkhaGIx6DWxyYWED5EFPWI3/GZ0xzTbpL83DUVUtS/ediGlJTj5NyBlLtEcuRLv
XE5a6kiJU6ZLCcSmSDdBluUKyuUqqIwddbhBpeNik8bzS3aT6kOxhwlOIQZeunaIaLdBDlUGcQ6i
1Op7pe9lurj06xerCWDRwcQjFjpj3ZVCR1z9NuCRkV+YCYWS
```

Here PHP code encoded with obsoleted encoder 7.0(PHP 5.6 and below):

```
<?php //0046b
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);

?>
HR+cPztBoaaSBCzkpN9VQlx61diBTKY3K9Mo6QkiHctnYMVjt+wt5LKPQiXrdL2L4kPfUYzmMESC
lcAxEsG3poSelwD+kdd08ZYEwxLBpp7ygESUJ3bafOEpLpdkuPTvrz8X69Zu7qlvz818LBJQe/Tz
mxcC8cJvxWBWfyVldqFIfwAdP7FElroV7giVwaoFWplm+3Ut5FutMAWRd7f95Gb9ghPgLSMS7crq
4Qx1E3bK1BTXgDrKZ0RfRbd2gSLZlA97dGwTbM8ccs9bbie3LGVEtZlGR/J9Bz142go08cr/Taym
xfs4+ITF7iqEk8gWdywHV1tYKJvc26w4bpIW51IcXdcd0QDIdhx4PfTVmMxyVVmqPuVv8L23N6EI
sTAuCNc5o8LjRzW2Yp4ctMJVPKkjWmg4HKs95xZABDbJ
```

Comment: It is possible to get for 7.1 7.2 7.3 php version ?

Answer (score 2):

another method is

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```

and look under Additional Module heading, you should be able to see

ionCube Loader